# Redux. How could I nest container inside component explicitly passing the store to props?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have next React Redux JSX markup:

```html
<Connect(JobsComponent)>
  <JobsComponent>
    <div>
      <WrapperCustomDumpArrowFunctionComponent>
        <CustomDumpArrowFunctionComponent>
          {
            someCondition ?
              <Connect(WorkflowContainer) someProp="someData" /> :
              null
          }
        </CustomDumpArrowFunctionComponent>
      </WrapperCustomDumpArrowFunctionComponent>
    </div>
  </JobsComponent>
</Connect(JobsComponent)>
```

Where `Connect(...)` node is a container created using redux `connect` function.

The others either simple DOM component or simple arrow component rendered using props (`({ props }) => (<div>{props}</div>)`).

Also `Connect(JobsComponent)` the last one element, which yet contains the `store` in the context.

So, when condition became true an error is received:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(WorkflowsContainer)". Either wrap the root component in a , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(WorkflowsContainer)".

How could I avoid this issue or explicitly pass the store to the WorkflowsContainer?

React 15.4.2
Redux 3.6.0
P.S. Everything in the [Redux Troubleshooting](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#user-content-could-not-find-store-in-either-the-context-or-props) is covered and exists.

Comment: You sure on your markup? <Connect(JobsComponent)>.. Doesnt really look like a React component

Comment: @KornholioBeavis looks like he copied the "dom" from the React dev tools.

Comment: OP, did you wrap your project in a store provider? http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#passing-the-store

Comment: @KornholioBeavis Excluding some unnecessary code it looks like this: `class JobsComponent extends PureComponent {
  render () {
    return (
      <ArrowComponent>
        ...
      </ArrowComponent>
    );
  }
}

export default CSSModules(JobsComponent, styles);`

Comment: @Tyler Sebastian yes I copied, it is easier to read this way. And yes I used Provider on the very top level. The `JobsComponent` is connected component, which is used  in the `react-router`'s `IndexRoot` component, which is wrapped into `<Provider store={store}>`.

Comment: I think we need more code - and actual code, please, not from React dev tools.

Comment: @TylerSebastian sure. Have created one with file structure and some fixtures where NDA is applied. [extracted code](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rth8BgFfUzl52lnYiims)

Comment: Could it be an issue because I render in `document.body` dynamically on one of the nested level? If so, then original question is here – How could I explicitly pass the `store`?

Comment: Okay, so I have found the issue, but with that said, I have not managed to find clear solution of explicitly passing the store. So the issue was in that, one of my nested components was moving on render its `children` to `document.body`, that's why the error was triggered. So the solution was to pass the `store` to the `children` which are moved, like this: `import store from '[PATH_TO_STORE_FILE]';` and then `<Workflows locales={locales} store={store} />`. As long as imports are immutable and Singletons in works fine. Anyway thanks guys for helping.